# Question about growth of a convex function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convex-analysis

Let me define it first. Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function such that $$f(0)=0, \qquad f(-x)=f(x), \qquad \lim\limits_{x \to \infty}f(x) = \infty$$ then it is said to be a $\Delta_2$ function if it satisfies the following

$$f(2x)\leq Kf(x) \text{ for } x\geq x_0\geq0 \text{ and for some } K>0$$

---

What I understand by above is that it basically showing the growth of $f$ like for a fixed $K>0$ and for all value of $x$, rate of $f(x)$ will be faster than $f(2x)$ also we can see that growth of $f(2x)$ is controlled by $f(x)$, I mean $f(2x)$ can not grow freely.If what I understood is correct then I want to understand the geometrical interpretation of this and if I am not correct please correct me.

Comment: I don't think the geometric intuition comes much simpler than what you basically said: for large $x$, the function's value at $x$ is controlled by the function's value twice as far down the line, at $2x$. This includes functions that grow like polynomials, but excludes functions that grow like exponentials. Maybe you just need to work through a few concrete examples to get a better feel for it?

Comment: If the function is convex then $f(x)<\frac12 (f(2x)+f(0))=\frac12 f(2x)$ since f(0)=0 so if $f(2x)<K f(x)$ then $f(2x)<K \frac12 f(2x)$ so we have to have $K>2$ or $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ but you claim that $f(\infty)=\infty$ so it must be that $K>2$.

Answer (score 0):

If a function is convex then $$f(ta+(1-t)b)\leq tf(a)+(1-t)f(b)$$ for all $b>a$, $t\in[0,1]$,
so setting $a=0$, $b=2x$, and $t=\frac12$ we have $f(x)\leq\frac12(f(0)+f(2x))=\frac12f(2x)$ since $f(0)=0$. Then if $f(2x)\leq K f(x)$, $f(2x)\leq \frac{K}2f(2x)$ so $K\geq2$ or $f(x)=0$ for all $x$, but this is ruled out by the limit as $x$ goes to infinity. The upper limit $f(2x)=Kf(x)$ gives us $\log f(2x)=\log K+\log f(x)$ which has the solution $f(x)=x^{\log_2 K}$, so if $K=4$ then $f(x)=x^2$ etc.

So the possible "geometry" of this function is any convex (increasing with a rate of increase which is increasing) function which is between $y=x$ (the $K=2$ case) and $y=x^{\log_2 K}$ and passes through the origin.

Comment: I think the majority of your "<" should be "$\leqslant$" (`\leqslant`). Anyway, +1